# Can I change the type of an index on the fly without re-creating the table?

Tags: sqlite, indexing, collation, system.data.sqlite

I have always used a custom implementation of SQLite, and it had the "LATIN_NOCASE" collation.
I am now using System.Data.SQLite, and it doesn't have this collation, as I have found out now.

I would therefore like to change all indexes from LATIN_NOCASE to NOCASE.

Can I somehow do that with one line of code, or do I have to recreate the table / the indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is designed as a lightweight, embedded database where large changes to the database are not supposed to happen at runtime, so it has no ALTER INDEX command: http://www.sqlite.org/lang.html.